# Calculation of animation $Aborted

Tags: animation

When I run below code the calculation of animation are aborted and in the animation window is visible the information "$Aborted". Why?

```
r[u_, v_] := { u + Cos[v], u - Sin[v], u };
vM = Pi/2;
uconr = r[u, vM];
uM = 1;
vconr = r[uM, v];
ru = D[r[u, v], u];
rv = D[r[u, v], v];
crs = Cross[ru, rv];
rNunit = crs/Sqrt[crs.crs];
rV = ParametricPlot3D[r[u, v], {u, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}];
uconrV = ParametricPlot3D[uconr, {u, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Magenta];
vconrV = ParametricPlot3D[vconr, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Cyan];
runorm = Sqrt[ru.ru] /. u -> uM /. v -> vM;
rvnorm = Sqrt[rv.rv] /. u -> uM /. v -> vM;
rNunitScale = 2.5;
rNV = Graphics3D[{Red, 
    Arrow[{r[uM, 
       vM], (r[uM, vM] + (rNunit /. u -> uM /. v -> vM)*
         rNunitScale)}]}];
opV = ParametricPlot3D[(r[u, v] + s*(ru + rv) + 
       k*Cross[ru + rv, rNunit]) /. u -> uM /. v -> vM, {s, -3, 
    3}, {k, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7], Green], 
   Mesh -> None];


Show[{rV, uconrV, vconrV, rNV, opV}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-3, 3}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Verdena"}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Ticks -> Automatic, 
 AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style[Framed["Wektor normalny i płaszczyzna styczna do powierzchni",
     FrameStyle -> Red], 13, Darker[Blue, .6], 
   Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]], 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Verdena"}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]


uconrA[v0_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[r[u, v0], {u, -Pi, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Magenta];
vconrA[u0_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[r[u0, v], {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Cyan];
rNA[u0_, v0_] := 
  Graphics3D[{Red, 
    Arrow[{r[u0, 
       v0], (r[u0, v0] + (rNunit /. u -> u0 /. v -> v0)*
         rNunitScale)}]}];
opA[u0_, v0_] := 
  ParametricPlot3D[(r[u, v] + s*(ru + rv) + 
       k*Cross[ru + rv, rNunit]) /. u -> u0 /. v -> v0, {s, -1, 
    1}, {k, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.7], Green], 
   Mesh -> None]; 

Animate[Show[{rV, uconrA[v0], vconrA[u0], rNA[u0, v0], opA[u0, v0]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-3, 3}}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Verdena"}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Ticks -> Automatic, 
  AxesStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[Framed[
     "Wektor normalny i płaszczyzna styczna do powierzchni", 
     FrameStyle -> Red], 13, Darker[Blue, .6], 
    Background -> Lighter[LightYellow]], 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Verdena"}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1], {v0, 0, 2 Pi}, {u0, -3.1, 3.1}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

When I run upper code the calculation of animation are aborted and in the animation window is visible the information "$Aborted". Why?

I am asking everyone to check the above code again. During this edition in the Animation code I added the element `opA [u0, v0]` which before I forgot to insert, for which I am sorry and this is the element of the code that causes the problem.

Comment: Most likely because it took too long to finish, see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SynchronousUpdating.html

Comment: It works without problems on my machine (Mathematica 11.0.1 for macos). Try to refresh the kernel (e.g. with `Exit`) and try again.

Comment: I am asking everyone to check the above code again. During this edition in the Animation code I added the element opA [u0, v0] which before I forgot to insert, for which I am sorry and this is the element of the code that causes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution to my problem. Note that the vector

```
(r[u, v] + s*(ru + rv) + k*Cross[ru + rv, rNunit])
```

it's a complicated and time-consuming calculation. Therefore, it is necessary to calculate the calculations before it is put - as a result of the calculation - into the function `opA [u0_, v0_]`.

So we mark `calcv = (r[u, v] + s*(ru + rv) + k*Cross[ru + rv, rNunit]);` and put the `calcv` into the function `opA [u0_, v0_]`.

Now we can do all the code in the notebook without fear that something will go wrong.

This is an instructive example that complicated and time-consuming calculations, which will be performed repeatedly, should be performed once, and the result obtained in such a way should be substituted in a place where it will be used many times!